# Z3 complains that assumption is not a propositional variable, even when it actually is

Tags: z3

I'm using the Java API. This is a minimal working example for this warning:

```
HashMap<String, String> cfg = new HashMap<String, String>();
cfg.put("model", "true");
Context ctx = new Context(cfg);
Solver solver = ctx.mkSolver();
BoolExpr a = ctx.mkBoolConst("a");
BoolExpr b = ctx.mkBoolConst("b");
BoolExpr and = ctx.mkAnd(a,b); 
solver.check(and);
```

For this small program, Z3 complained that:

> WARNING: an assumption must be a propositional variable or the
>   negation of one

Unless I misunderstood something, `and` is a propositional variable, so I do not understand why there is this warning. Moreover, the `check` method takes an array of `BoolExpr` as parameters, so why it requires a propositional variable?

My question: **can I safely ignore this warning**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `and` is not a propositional variable, but it's a propositional term (or in other words a BoolExpr). Assumption literals for `solver.check(...)` need to be variables or the negation of a variable, i.e., `a` or `not a`, but not `a and b`.

This warning is not safe to ignore, because it means that Z3 will ignore those assumptions, i.e., you may get unexpected results.

Just to avoid confusion: the arguments to `solver.check(...)` are *assumption* literals, they are not *assertions*, i.e., if we want to check whether `and` is satisfiable we need to first assert it and then ask the solver to check without further assumptions, e.g.,

```
...
solver.assert(and);
solver.check();
```