# Z3 unsat-core: an assumption must be a propositional variable or the negation of one

Tags: c++, z3

I am working upon C++ Z3 unsat core,

```
Z3_parse_smtlib_string(ctx,
    "(benchmark tst :extrafuns ((b1 Bool) (b2 Bool) (b3 Bool) (x Int) (y Int)) :formula (=> b1 (> x y)) :formula (=> b2 (= x 0)) :formula (=> b3 (> y 0)))",0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0);
num_formulas = Z3_get_smtlib_num_formulas(ctx); 
std::vector<expr> assumptions;
for (i = 0; i < num_formulas; i++) 
{
    Z3_ast f = Z3_get_smtlib_formula(ctx, i);
    z3::expr e(ctx, f);
    assumptions.push_back(e);
    s.add(e);
}
s.check(3,&assumptions[0]) ;
expr_vector core = s.unsat_core();
std::cout << "size: " << core.size() << "\n";
for (unsigned i = 0; i < core.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << core[i] << "\n";
}
```

However, it throws a warning: an assumption must be a propositional variable or the negation of one.
Also, the unsat core size returned is 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Z3 complains that assumption is not a propositional variable, even when it actually is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883493/z3-complains-that-assumption-is-not-a-propositional-variable-even-when-it-actua)

Comment: That link suggests to assert expressions, which is already performed in my question when we do s.add(e)

Comment: the linked answer specifies that you can't add **any expression** to the set of assumptions, but only atomic boolean variables, or their negation. The warning you are getting is *z3* telling you that your code violates this rule

Comment: If you read the formulas, you can see that b1, b2, b3 are boolean variables. When we add it to the solver , by means of, s.add(e), we are asserting boolean where e evaluates to boolean b=>(> x y).

Comment: Well, I might be wrong, since I can not reproduce your code snippet. So are you claiming that `(=> b1 (> x y))` is never added to `assumptions` at line `assumptions.push_back(e);` ?

Comment: It is added to assumptions, however it does not work as expected for the line `s.check(3,&assumptions[0]) ;`

Comment: That was my point, that you shouldn't add `(=> b1 (> x y))` directly to the assumption list, because then `s.check(3,&assumptions[0]) ;` won't work. I don't understand exactly where I am wrong according to you, could you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution for generating unsat core by introducing tracked assertions,

1. we need to configure unsat-core to true.
2. We need to create boolean variables to track assertions

   ```
   Z3_parse_smtlib_string(ctx,
   "(benchmark tst :extrafuns ( (x Int) (y Int)) :formula (> x y) :formula (= x 0) :formula (> y 0) )",
   0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0);
   params p(ctx);
   p.set(":unsat-core", true); 
   solver s(ctx);
   s.set(p);
   num_formulas = Z3_get_smtlib_num_formulas(ctx);
   for (i = 0; i < num_formulas; i++) 
   {
       Z3_ast f = Z3_get_smtlib_formula(ctx, i);           
       z3::expr e(ctx, f);
       std::stringstream qname; 
       qname << "q" << i;
      s.add(e , qname.str().c_str());
   }
   if (s.check() == z3::sat)
      std::cout << s.get_model() << "\n";
   else
      std::cout << "UNSAT?!\n";
   expr_vector core = s.unsat_core();
   std::cout << core << "\n";
   ```